# Unable to save many-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, save

I have the following tables/views

```
Users (View)
-> UserId
-> Name

Roles (Table)
-> RoleId
-> Name

UserRoles (Table)
-> UserId
-> RoleId
```

and the classes

```
public class Role{
     public int RoleId{get;set}
     public string Name{get;set}
}

public class User{
     public int UserId{get;set}
     public string Name{get;set}
     public ICollection<Role> Roles{get;set}
}
```

and the save method

```
using (var helper = new DbContext())
{
     helper.Users.Attach(user);
     helper.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see above, the Users is a view and UserRoles is a mapping table. I am able to retrieve User entities along with the mapped Roles. But while saving it is not throwing any exceptions nor is it saving. I tried checking the db using profiler and it is not even hitting the db.

Since Users is a view I don't want to save the User entity but only the changes made in the Roles collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot save anything. `Attach` puts the whole object graph into the context, but in state `Unchanged`. If all objects in the context are unchanged `SaveChanges` won't issue any command to the DB (because for EF nothing has changed).

If you want to make changes which EF recognizes as such you must first attach the object which represents the state in the Db and then make your changes, something like:

```
using (var helper = new DbContext())
{
    helper.Users.Attach(user);
    helper.Roles.Attach(myNewRole);
    user.Name = myNewName;
    user.Roles.Add(myNewRole);
    // etc.
    helper.SaveChanges();
}
```

Alternatively you can mark the user as modified:

```
helper.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

But I believe this only affects scalar properties of the entity and it doesn't solve the problem to add a new role to the user.

Comment: I tried a similar thing. I removed all the roles and attached the User entity and then added back all the roles. This saved the mapping but it also added a new role to the Roles table. This is what is not expected. It should only add the mapping.

Comment: @Hemanshu Bhojak: Then you must also attach the role to the context **before** you add it to the user's role collection. It leaves the role itself in `Unchanged` state and avoids to add a new role to the DB. I've changed my code above to show this.